# add cssClass to CurrentNode in asp.net Navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

Here is my code :

```
<div class="Cat-list unselectable" style="font-weight:bold;">
    <div class="right-bar-nav-item">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkHome" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="right-bar-nav-item">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("description") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
            </div>                              
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

I'd like to give class ".selected" to Current Node. example: if its Default.aspx then it should change from `<div class="right-bar-nav-item">` to this `<div class="right-bar-nav-item selected">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); 

    // now grab every link from the navigation
    $('.menu a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is how you can do this in javascript.

Comment: cool , using javascript was my plan B. I changed '.menu a' to '.right-bar-nav-item' and $(this).addClass('selected') to $(this).closest('div.right-bar-nav-item').addClass('selected') and now its working though